# Is this division algorithm proof valid?

Tags: number-theory

I was doing a proof of the division algorithm for positive integers, and I wanted to know if my proof was valid. Also, how might I generalize my proof for all the integers?

Show that for $$n, p \in \mathbb{Z} ^ +, n = pq + r$$

This is my attempted proof. Please tell me if anything is incorrect and correct me if I'm wrong! Thank you!

My attempt:

Let $$S = \{ q \text{ }| \text{ } pq \geq n, q \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \} $$

We know that this set is not empty, since we can take $q = n.$

Now, from the well-ordering principle, we know that there is a smallest element $q_0 \in S.$ Then we know that $p(q_0 - 1) < n.$ From this inequality, we can say that $n - p(q_0 - 1) = r, r \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$ If we now let $k = q_0 - 1$, we get $n = pk + r.$

Comment: It would be more meaningful if you write at the beginning what restrictions you desire for $q$ and $r$. For otherwise, you can always take $q = 0$ and $r = n$. You probably wish something like $0 \le r < q$. (Although by your proof, it looks like you have $1 \le r \le q$.)

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. I'll fix my proof.

Comment: You need to prove $\,r < p.\,$ It's easier to consider the least nonegative element of $\,n-p\Bbb Z\,$